# UIImagePicker not functioning properly

Tags: swift, firebase, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to allow users to change their profile picture and save it into Firebase.  I built the code and my app runs. However, I am not seeing the ability to change the profile picture. My code is below:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class EditProfileVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(profileImageView)
        setupProfileImageView()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func setupProfileImageView() {
        profileImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive=true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    }

    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()
}
```

I also created an extension file that handles the imagePicker:

```
import UIKit

extension EditProfileVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @objc func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print(info)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        print("Canceled Picker")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String :   AnyObject])
        {
        if let img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage       {

            profileImageView.image = img
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am not plugging in correctly or am I missing a key piece of code?

Comment: @Sh_Khan thank you for your assistance, I updated my code above. I plugged in your code as well, however, I am still not allowed to update an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this block of code from start of your code because it is duplicate with 1 capital letter, and I think you are assigning image to duplicate one.

```
let ProfileImageView: UIImageView = {
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "users")
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return imageView
}()
```

Comment: I updated my code to show that I had removed the code.

Comment: Is there anything that I should call after deleting that code?

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this in my projects.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage

    } else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage

    }
    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        userImg = selectedImage

    }
    userImageView.image = userImg
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I used this code and it is still not working. Is there a code that I  should use to create the userImageView and userImg?